# Как изменить html хука woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hmtl

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в хлебных крошках разделитель был не "/", а "-". Вставил в свой html хук `<?php woocommerce_breadcrumb() ?>`. Теперь нужно просто изменить html. Не понимаю как это сделать. Спасибо за ответ :)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Нужно сделать так, чтобы в хлебных крошках разделитель был не "/", а
> "-".

```
$args = array(
    'delimiter' => '-' 
);
woocommerce_breadcrumb( $args );
```

См. документацию по функции https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce_breadcrumb/

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось.